# Asp net core read or write views at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view, runtime

I have an asp .net core project. At runtime, I want to read and modify the views in my views folder in an editor, and at the same time, I want to save them and instantly reflect them on the site.

Can I both read and update views with the familiar file read and write method. Is it okay for me to do this at runtime?
How can I do this and what is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package to enable runtime compilation.

1.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.

2.Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project

Comment: Hi Rena,
First of all, thank you very much for your answer.
I would like to do a test based on your answer. However, I couldn't figure out how to do this. Will it be enough for me to install the package you specified? After installing this package, how do I read and write related views?

I'm currently reading it from the view folder with streamreader and writing it again with streamwriter and I get what I want. However, I don't know if it will cause me problems when I throw it live. I'm wondering the best way to do this.

Comment: Hi @SerkanCA, After you install the package and add this services in Startup, you could see the changes at runtime if you change the view or backend code in visual studio.

Comment: Then I will ask you this question.
Let's say I installed the packages as you said and added them to the startup;

Now I have an admin panel. In this admin panel, I list all the views in the views folder. When the user selects a view here, I display it in a code editor. Later, when the user makes changes to this code and says save, I write the relevant change to the existing view file with streamwriter.

In this case, is it true that I won't get any errors because I write to that view at runtime?